# Ionic 4: Is it better to declare all pages and components in root?

Tags: angular, ionic4

I would like to know what is the best way to organize an ionic app. 
The app I'm developing is getting bigger, and I started having problems with components or pages declared here but not here, so I cannot use some components or pipes, etc...

Until now I tried to declare components, pages where they are used, but I saw some app where all pages, components, pipes... were declared in app.module.ts which prevent any declaration problems I guess.
 Does it change the performance? Is there other way to organize an app?

I got the problem when I created a custom pipe and tried to use it in a component only declare in a page actually. I declared the pipe in the app.module.ts but it wasn't recognized in the component...

thanks for your help. If the question is not clear, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

It is always suggested to create a new module when you don't have any interaction between two of the modules.
And by the way in Ionic Page acts as a module by it self. Just make sure you maintain the components inside pages or module properly.

Comment: Okay it gives me better idea. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

it is batter to create new small small reusable component. because you can reduce the code and easy to maintain